# How can I send protobuf file from Flutter, by RawSocket?

Tags: flutter, raw-sockets

I want to send the protobuf file to server but I don't know how to make a protobuf file, and the way to send it.

Comment: Sorry, I mean the protobuf object. How can I make the protobuf object from flutter. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the protobuf package https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/protoc_plugin more instructions found on the same page

```
dependencies:
   protoc_plugin: ^0.10.2



import 'package:protobuf/protobuf.dart';
```